# Help using MUX in Logisim

Tags: logisim

I am experiencing difficulties using Logisim whilst trying to implement a simple 2-to-1 MUX. I keep getting "Incompatible Widths" error messages no matter how I connect it. Any idea what's causing this and how it may be fixed?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think mux databits needs to be set to 1. If you right click on the mux or your pins, you can change the number of databits in the lefthand attribute window. Also, on the mux, you probably don't need the enable input, so turn that off.

Your mux should have only 1 output line. Your control line is supposed to select which of your inputs will be connected to your single output line. Having 2 output lines doesn't fit the normal design of a 2-line to 1-line mux.

You can assign wider paths to the mux inputs and outputs, but it doesn't appear to be what you are trying to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've selected a 2 x 2-bit-input to 2-bit-output mux.

You can either (a) choose a 1-bit mux or (b) connect up the second bit of each mux input to 0, leave the second bit of the output unconnected and let synthesis optimise and create a 1-bit mux for you.

(a) is the long-term solution but (b) may be quick to test and prove.